# Accessing files in public storage on Android 12 and above

Tags: storage, scoped, androidsdk31

I have an App that's been on the play store for about 6 years, and I just did an update and was required by Google to upgrade to at least SDK version 31.  This App controls a device via Bluetooth and has been storing configuration files in "Android/data/com.mycompany.MY_APP_FOLDER".  However, with the newer SDK's my App can no longer access that folder as that is now limited to specific types of Apps, and requires Google approval. So I store new files in the App's scoped storage, but I need to provide the user a way to access their old files and copy them to the scoped storage.

The only work around I have found is to have the user plug the phone into their PC and copy the files using File Explorer.  However, I've tested this on a dozen different phones and the process is not consistent or reliable.  I've also considered using a file explorer on the phone that has the correct permissions, however, this could be a lengthy process as it may involve a large number of files.